# SipAudioCall without registering a local SipProfile

Tags: android, sip

I'm trying to use the native Android SIP stack to make direct SIP calls within a LAN. It appears that within the native stack, you are required to register a local profile in order to make SIP calls.

Here is the code I (try to) use to register a profile. I do not have a SIP server on this network, so I just use localhost for a domain.

```
    if (mSipManager == null) {
        mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(mContext);

        try {
            SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("foo", "localhost");
            builder.setPassword("bar");

            mSipProfile = builder.build();
            mSipManager.register(mSipProfile, 30000, new SipRegistrationListener() {

                public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Registering with profile with SIP Server. URI: " + localProfileUri);
                }

                public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Registered with profile with SIP Server. URI: " + localProfileUri);
                }

                public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                                 String errorMessage) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Registration failed.  Code: " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
                    Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
                }
            });
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to set up local SipProfile.", e);
        } catch (SipException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to open local SipProfile.", e);
        }
    }
```

Elsewhere, here is my code for making a call:

```
try {
        Log.v(TAG, "VOIP Supported: " + SipManager.isVoipSupported(mActivity));
        Log.v(TAG, "SIP API Supported: " + SipManager.isApiSupported(mActivity));

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(mSipUri);
        SipProfile remote = builder.build();

        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onCalling(SipAudioCall call) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SIP Call initiating...");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SIP Call established.");

                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                call.toggleMute();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                Log.d(TAG, "SIP Call ended.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SipAudioCall call, int errorCode, String errorMessage) {
                Log.e(TAG, "SIP Call Error. Code: " + Integer.toString(errorCode));
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            }
        };

        mSipCall = mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile, remote, listener, 10);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to set up remote SipProfile.", e);
    } catch (SipException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "SipAudioCall error.", e);
    }
```

This all results in the following logcat output:

```
 11-20 11:46:33.150    1412-1412/package.name E/XmlTest﹕ 1- Unable to open local SipProfile.
         android.net.sip.SipException: SipService.createSession() returns null
         at android.net.sip.SipManager.register(SipManager.java:481)
```

I'm unable to find further details as to why createSession is returning null; is it because I've not provided a valid server for the profile to register with? If so, is there a way to use the native SIP stack without registering with a server?

Comment: Did you forget mSipManager.open(...)? This did cause SipService.createSession() returns null for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem is that Android's SIP stack appears to require the local SIP Profile you provide to the SIPManager (in the first codeblock above, represented by `builder` and `mSipProfile`) to have a valid IP address supplied to it.

Where I originally specified "localhost", you must actually provide the IP address of whatever interface you are making the SIP call over; if you are using a VPN, you must provide the IP of the VPN interface.

Comment: I have a problem like this. Can you please say what did you write exactly as this parameter?